# Start an async process - can/should I use asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: there's a long running process, i.e. rabbitmq consumer. When it receives a specific message, it should start a parallel process that does something (whatever... print, sleep for a minute...) and finishes. In the meantime, the main process still consumes messages.

This scenario could be simplified to this example:

```
import time

@this_should_run_in_parallel
def background_foo():
    for _ in range(3):
        print('zxc')
        time.sleep(1)

for k in range(10):
    print('abc')
    if k == 5:
        background_foo()
    time.sleep(1)

# for loop is printing abc
# but once k == 5 the parallel function also start printing
# for loop goes on
# desired output

abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
zxc
abc
zxc
abc
zxc
abc
abc
abc
```

Is this something asyncio should be used for, or should I stick to multiprocessing/threading modules?

Comment: What is problem with `threading`?

Comment: If you want it running concurrently then threading or asyncio is what you want, given your style of choice. If you want it running in _parallel_ then look at multiprocessing

Comment: As Will said, threads will give you concurrently but only mutliprocessing will give you parallel

Answer (score 1):

Yes [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) can deal with that, but you have to pick the right tool depending on the nature of the task:

[image: Asyncio flow chart]

Links:

- [asycio standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)
- [aio-lib](https://github.com/aio-libs), [third-party](https://github.com/python/asyncio/wiki/ThirdParty)
- [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) (+ [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor))
- [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) (+ [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor))